# how can i avoid eval in this situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Writing a title_tag helper, i want to have the following yml file structure

```
index: Hello {{@game.name}}
edit: Edit {{@game.name}} - {{@game.classification}}
```

by then i take the I18n translation string and need to replace {{var}} with actual context.

```
title = I18n.t "title_tags.#{namespace}.#{controller_name}.#{action_name}", default: ""

title.scan(/\{\{.*?\}\}/).each do |replace|
  # transform {{@game.name}} => @game.name
  var = replace.gsub(/\{|\}/, "")
  title.gsub! replace, eval(var)
end
```

this is working pretty sweet. on the other side, there is a possibility that a user might upload some game **with a name "system(rm -rf /*)"** which might cause some real danger for us ?

are there any possibilities to get this running in a safer way?

### Edit

Thanks to Axel i could end with this cool stuff

```
 title.scan(/\{\{.*?\}\}/).each do |replace|
    var = replace.gsub(/\{|\}/, "")                        

    # catch "resource" (like resource-controller)
    if var.starts_with? "resource"
      @tempresource = resource
      var.gsub!("resource", "@tempresource")
    end

    # @game or @game.name
    if var.starts_with?("@")          
      content = var.split('.').inject(nil){|clazz, method| clazz.nil? ? instance_variable_get(method) : clazz.send(method)}
      title.gsub! replace, content
    end
  end
```

working brilliant!

Comment: Take a look at http://liquidmarkup.org

Comment: i know about liquid and read the code of the parser.rb. can't really figure it out how they do it. looks like they wrote an own function comparable to eval. maybe you have a deeper inisght.
btw: cheers out of walle :-)

Comment: I wanted to suggest that you just *use* Liquid in your project, not re-implement it yourself ;-)

Comment: that was "obvious". and obvious i already tried it
Liquid::Template.parse("Hallo {{@game.name}}").render is returning "Hallo ". maybe i get the point wrong of how to use liquid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use send instead of eval:

```
content = var.split('.').inject(nil){|clazz, method| clazz.nil? ? instance_variable_get(method) : clazz.send(method)}
title.gsub! replace, content
```

Comment: any ideas for doing it with local variables? i.e string = "Hallo {{player}}"? fortunately we shouldnt have those inside of a yml file, but you never know...

Comment: `Binding#local_variable_get`