# Validate ERB template before rendering

Tags: ruby, erb

The ruby ERB class will silently continue if a value is missing in a template.

For example `@config['bar']` and `ENV['DOESNTEXIST']` are undefined.

```
require 'erb'
@config = {}
@config['foo'] = 42
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  FOO=<%= @config['foo'] %>
  BAR=<%= @config['bar'] %>
  LANG=<%= ENV['LANG'] %>
  BAD=<%= ENV['DOESNTEXIST'] %>
EOF
template.result(binding)
```

Output

```
FOO=42
BAR=  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
BAD=
```

Desired Output

```
Warning: @config['bar'] is undefined
Warning: ENV['DOESNTEXIST'] is undefined
FOO=42
BAR=  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
BAD=
```

**Is there a way to warn if an ERB template has a nil or undefined value?

Is there a way to show all variables in an erb template so I can iterate over them for validation?**

I don't know all the values of the template ahead of time since users can specify their own templates.

---

What I've tried:

`template.inspect` gives me a string showing the placeholders. I *could* filter on substrings but that is unreliable.

```
template.inspect
 => "#<ERB:0x00007ff4e50b1288 @safe_level=nil, @src=\"#coding:UTF-8\\n_erbout = +''; _erbout.<< \\\"  FOO=\\\".freeze; _erbout.<<(( @config['foo'] ).to_s); _erbout.<< \\\"\\\\n  BAR=\\\".freeze\\n; _erbout.<<(( @config['bar'] ).to_s); _erbout.<< \\\"\\\\n  LANG=\\\".freeze\\n; _erbout.<<(( ENV['LANG'] ).to_s); _erbout.<< \\\"\\\\n  BAD=\\\".freeze\\n; _erbout.<<(( ENV['DOESNT EXIST'] ).to_s); _erbout.<< \\\"\\\\n\\\".freeze\\n; _erbout\", @encoding=#<Encoding:UTF-8>, @frozen_string=nil, @filename=nil, @lineno=0>"`
```

---

**Update**: I admit the way this question is phrased isn't very clear. The real meat of the question is how to turn a string like `"@config['foo']"` into a variable like `@config['foo']`? 
I've learned this is commonly done with `eval()` which has known issues. 
Related question: [how can i avoid eval in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961998/how-can-i-avoid-eval-in-this-situation)

Comment: ERB won't do this for you. I would suggest writing some sort of `validate_config(@config)` method to do your checks.

Comment: Fair enough. I still need to cleanly get the variables from the template somehow. Is 'grep' the best way?

Comment: "Users can specify their own templates" ... how much do you trust these users? Because this sounds pretty insecure

Comment: It's a command line utility used internally at the company. Very similar to `helm template`. Users define the entire config file, the utility just helps paramaterize it.

Comment: A better way of doing this would be via JSON or if you need HTML then XSLT

Answer (score 1):

Use `fetch`. From the docs:

> Returns a value from the hash for the given key. If the key can’t be found, there are several options: With no other arguments, it will raise a KeyError exception; if default is given, then that will be returned; if the optional code block is specified, then that will be run and its result returned.

It isn't just ERB that has the behavior you describe; any Ruby array will return `nil` anytime something is not in the hash. We want it to 'fail fast', as soon as something is missing.

```rb
2.5.1 :000 > {foo: "something"}[:foo]
 => "something"
2.5.1 :001 > {foo: "something"}[:bar]
 => nil
```

Use `fetch` to access items in `@config`:

```rb
2.5.1 :000 > @config = {foo: "something"}
 => "something"
2.5.1 :001 > @config.fetch(:foo)
 => "something"
2.5.1 :002 > @config.fetch(:bar)
KeyError (key not found: :bar)
```

Using `fetch` in your code to retrieve the nonexistent `bar` returns the following:

```
undefined local variable or method `‘bar’' for main:Object
```

This isn't a warning as the original question asked, it’s an error. If just a warning was desired, `fetch` accepts a default as the second argument that could serve that role.

[fetch docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

Comment: This is helpful and may solve half the problem. The real root of the problem is how to get the variables out of the erb template.

Comment: That sounds hard, and it's not clear to from your question why that's necessary. If you have access to `@config`, as the code shows, why not validate it before using it in the template?

Comment: Agreed, I didn't phrase the question well. I now know that what I'm really looking for is `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use regex to filter out all patterns like `<%= -%>` and `<%= %>`.

```
text.scan(/<%= ?([^>]+) -?%>/)
```

Which will return

```
 => [["@config['foo']"], ["@config['bar']"], ["ENV['LANG']"], ["ENV['DOESNTEXIST']"]]
```

Then use `eval()` to verify the variable `@config['foo']` exists. Because `eval()` is dangerous, it is best to white list the variables it is allowed to evaluate. In this case only strings like `@config[;` and `ENV['` are permitted.

```
require 'erb'
@config = {}
@config['foo'] = 42
text = <<-EOF
  FOO=<%= @config['foo'] %>
  BAR=<%= @config['bar'] %>
  LANG=<%= ENV['LANG'] %>
  BAD=<%= ENV['DOESNTEXIST'] %>
EOF
# Match strings like <%= -%> and <%= %>
variables = text.scan(/<%= ?([^>]+) -?%>/)
template = ERB.new text
template.result(binding)

# Only evaluate variables that start with '@config' or 'ENV'
variables.each do |variable|
  if variable.start_with?("@config")
    variable.sub!("@config", "")
    @config2 = builder.instance_variable_get("@config")
    puts "WARNING: Undefined variable: @config#{variable}" unless eval("@config2#{variable}")
  elsif variable.start_with?("ENV")
    puts "WARNING: Undefined variable: #{variable}" unless eval(variable)
  else
    raise "Variable '#{variable}' not allowed"
  end
end
```